# is this an upper bound for the square of a finite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that the derivative of a (long) function is negative. after a lot of simplifying, i need the following inequality to hold:

$\displaystyle \Big ( \sum_{i=1}^k n_i \Big )^2 < \Big ( \sum_{i=1}^k in_i \Big ) \Big ( \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n_i}{i} \Big )$

where $\{n_i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is some random sequence. does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Bun'akovskij-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: You will only get strict inequality if $k \ge 2$

Comment: Then it will be true if  $2 \lt \frac{i}{j} + \frac{j}{i}$ for distinct positive integers $i,j$, and that is true since $(i - j)^2\gt 0$ if they are distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\left ( \sum_i x_i y_i \right )^2 \le \left (\sum_i x_i^2 \right )\left (\sum_i y_i^2 \right ) $$

where $x_i = \sqrt{i n_i}$ and $y_i = \sqrt{n_i/i}$.

and you are done.

Comment: but what is the condition for the inequality to be strict?

Comment: When $x_i \ne y_i$.